# I ran these commands and want to learn how to reverse them

Tags: command-line, apt, sudo

Please don't scorch me i'm still novice and only seeking help.
I ran the following commands:

```
echo "deb https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly release" 

sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tox.list

wget -qO - https://pkg.tox.chat/debian/pkg.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
```

I want to learn how to reverse these commands.

Answer (score 5):

You first command is not rightly put, perhaps you meant:

```
echo "deb https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly release" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tox.list
```

Now let's undo the commands one by one:

- You can either rename or remove the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tox.list` file:

  ```
  sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tox.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tox.list.bak
  ```

  Or

  ```
  sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tox.list
  ```
- Let's remove the `gpg` key of `tox` from the keyring of `apt`:

  ```
  sudo apt-key del 1A171ABE
  ```
- Let's remove the `apt-transport-https` package:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove apt-transport-https

  sudo apt-get purge apt-transport-https   ## Removing configuration files too
  ```